# android http request ignore cookie

Tags: android, cookies, httpclient

I am using DefaultHttpClient and want to prevent HttpClient from accepting and sending cookies. I tried something like this but 'CookiePolicy.IGNORE_COOKIE' is not available.

> mHttpClient.getParams().setParameter(ClientPNames.COOKIE_POLICY,
>   CookiePolicy.IGNORE_COOKIE);

Answer (score 2):

You can't just make up your own int Constants lol,

always check the API: http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/CookiePolicy.html

How about

> CookiePolicy.ACCEPT_NONE

http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/CookiePolicy.html#ACCEPT_NONE

Comment: if I use CookiePolicy.ACCEPT_NONE I get class cast exception

Comment: Hmmm what is the package of your HttpClient i.e. show us your imprts

Comment: java.net.CookiePolicy and for for httpclient org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient also org.apache.http.client.params.CookiePolicy does not have anything for ignore cookie